# Material assigning problem while projecting UV from view onto texture

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor, project

I have 2 rather screenshots than textures [image]

What I do is projecting my front and back sides of a character mesh onto these pictures.

I do that in this consequence:

1. assign a material to the mesh.
2. assign a new material to front faces > projecting them onto 1st pic
3. the same as the 2nd point but with the back side, selecting the back faces by inverting the first selection.

In result for some reason I get only one texture applied to the both sides, which can be switched by reordering them in material list. I want to admit that the front and back materials do have different textures assigned as base colors.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If everything seems to be set up correctly but it's still not working, it would be best to upload the file for further investigation.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I've just noticed that for some reason material assigning not working at all on this particular mesh.

Comment: "material assigning not working at all" cannot be possible I'd say, you can always assign a material to a mesh with faces somehow, no matter if UV mapping etc. is correct or not.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I attached the blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Solidify Modifier* you have set *Normals* to *Flip*. This in combination with having the *Material Offset* to 4, which refers to the fifth material slot (counting starts at 0, but since you have only two materials 0 and 1 the highest number is used) results in using material 1 for all visible faces.

Just for info on the *Material Offset* and *Rim* materials: like the word "offset" implies, it is always the slots offset based on the faces material. Which means, say *Material Offset* is 1 and *Rim* is 2, than a face which uses material slot 0 will get slot 1 for the solidified face and slot 2 for the rim, whereas a face using e.g. material slot 2 will get slot 3's material for solidified faces and slot 4 as material for the rim. If you now set *Normals* to *Flip*, the solidified face shows the assigned material but the original face shows the offset material.

When using only a single material or by resetting the *Material Offset* to 0, this problem will disappear and show the correctly assigned materials. However, flipped normals can also cause other problems with materials in rendering and for physics simulations etc. so you should rather disable the *Flip* option (this also enables you to still use the offset if you need it for special materials on the solidified faces).

[image]

Comment: Ooh thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, no - I'm sorry! Although this helps, it shouldn't be necessary. Under _Normals_ you have _Flip_ enabled, that's the problem. In your case for assigning the materials this might not matter very much, but having the normals flipped might also cause other problems so I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I learned a lot from this!

Comment: No problem. Since the _Normals_ menu wasn't unfolded I didn't look at it at first, but as soon as you turn on _Face Orientation_ in the _Overlays_ this becomes obvious.